# Modifying the FCPATH on index.php in subdirectory

Tags: codeigniter

On my codeigniter 3 project on wamp, I have a sub domain folder called cms-2 which has it's own index.php file `cms-1 > cms-2 > index.php`.

```
cms-1
cms-1 > application
cms-1 > cms-2
cms-1 > cms-2 > index.php
cms-1 > image
cms-1 > system
cms-1 > index.php
```

If I echo the FCPATH when I am on the sub domain it shows.

> C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\cms-1\cms-2/

**But I would like to know on that index.php file belonging to that sub domain instead of FCPATH showing**

> C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\cms-1\cms-2/

**Would like it to show**

> C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\cms-1/

**Question** How can I make the `define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__) .'/');` for the subdomain index.php only show `C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\cms-1/` when echo FCPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have got it working now here how I solved it. On the sub domain / sub directory index.php

I have had to make a couple of variables to make FCPATH produce what I wanted

```
$get_current_path_to_front = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/';

$set_new_path_to_front = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($get_current_path_to_front . '../')) . '/';

//echo $set_new_path_to_front;

// Path to the front controller (this file)
define('FCPATH', $set_new_path_to_front);

echo FCPATH;
```

So now when I echo FCPATH on sub domain produces

> C:\wamp\www\codeigniter\cms-1/